# composer Install/Update for laravel project return dependency error when i want to generate lock file

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to regenerate my `composer.lock` file with `composer.phar install`, but I'm running into this error:

> Problem 1
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.7 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.8 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.9 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.10 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.11 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.12 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.21 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.22 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.23 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.24 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.25 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.27 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.28 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.29 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.30 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.31 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.32 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.33 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.34 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.35 (conflict analysis result)
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36 (conflict analysis result)
> - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.2] require maximebf/debugbar ^1.16.3 -> satisfiable by maximebf/debugbar[v1.16.3, v1.16.4].
> - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.5.0, ..., v3.5.1] require php >=7.2 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - maximebf/debugbar v1.16.3 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - maximebf/debugbar v1.16.4 requires php ^7.1|^8 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.36] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/support[v6.20.0, ..., v6.20.7, v7.29.0, ..., v7.30.0] require php ^7.2.5|^8.0 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (7.0; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.2.9, ..., v3.3.3] require illuminate/support ^5.5|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.7, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.0].
> - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.2.6, ..., v3.2.8] require illuminate/support ^5.5|^6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.7].
> - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.2.3, ..., v3.2.5] require illuminate/support 5.5.x|5.6.x|5.7.x|5.8.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36].
> - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.2.0, ..., v3.2.2] require illuminate/support 5.5.x|5.6.x|5.7.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.7.28].
> - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.2.43, ..., v5.6.7], laravel/framework[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36]. They all replace tightenco/collect and thus cannot coexist.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36].
> - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ^3.2 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.2.0, ..., v3.5.1].

`composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "askedio/laravel5-profanity-filter": "^1.10",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.0 as 0.7.0",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "0.8.0 as 0.7.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "4.1.10",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "1.36.2",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "4.1.1",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
        "zizaco/entrust": "^1.9"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please upload your `composer.json` file

Comment: It looks like a lot of your libraries require php>7.1 and you have php 7.0 defined in your composer.json ("config": {
 "platform": {
     "php": "5.6"
 }). Can you remove that?

Comment: jason file added above check

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies in your `composer.json` cannot be resolved. The `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` version specified cannot be used with the `laravel/framework` version specified.

The lowest version of `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` allowed as specified is `3.2.0`. Looking at its `composer.json` file, it requires `laravel/framework` version `5.5.x` at a minimum. However, you've specified `laravel/framework` version `5.4.*`.

Since your dependencies can't be resolved, you get the error. You'll need to upgrade your `laravel/framework` version, or downgrade your `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` version.

Answer (score -1):

That's a difficult one: your `composer.json` requires `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` in v3.2, and this has a requirement for Laravel v5.5 or later. Through your own requirement, you restrict Laravel's version to v5.4 (through the line `"laravel/framework": "5.4.*"`).

A quick solution could be to either downgrade `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` to v2.4.3 (the latest one compatibel with Laravel 5.4), or upgrade your whole application to Laravel 5.5. You should do such upgrades from time to time - this helps you to manage such upgrades. The longer you wait, the more difficult it is to run upgrades, as your application and the packages you require drifted apart too much.

While you're upgrading: Why do you configure PHP 7.0? Your application should not run on such an outdated version any longer, as even the security support has ended two years ago